# What is the best data type to store prices upto 8 decimals + indicators in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, datatypes, money

I am developing a trading system which stores data in SQLite, consisting of OHLC and volume. I would also like to store some indicators like RSI etc I read the other answer which indicated integers as the data type. In my case I am looking at 8 digit precision which would slow down the calculations if I were to multiply every value by 1e8 Any recommendations are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FAQ pretty much explains the reason why you don't want to use their `REAL` data type for storing numbers with 8 decimal places.

> (16) Why does ROUND(9.95,1) return 9.9 instead of 10.0? Shouldn't 9.95 round up?

https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q16

## Workaround 1

The trick of using an `INTEGER` to achieve your required level of precision has been used since computers existed.

With today's powerful CPUs, I wouldn't worry about the overhead of any additional calculations.  You'll need to run benchmarks to (dis)prove my statement.

## Workaround 2

IMHO - You shouldn't use a tool that doesn't support your requirements.